# could not enter to root directory

Tags: command-line, sudo, su

```
$ sudo su   
Cannot execute /bin/ksh: No such file or directory

$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root

Password: 
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

This also is not changing my directory; I could not enter to root directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full command you tried, and the output it gave you.

Comment: oh, and /bin/ksh isn't a directory, its a shell, just like in /bin/ you should also have bash, zhs, etc...

Comment: I agree with the comments above. If you wish to have this resolved by other users, you need to give as much detail as possible. Also the use of bold can be seen as being rude and therefore may put others off answering.

Comment: The `root account` is locked by default on Ubuntu so to unlock you have to give it a password. Run `cat /etc/passwd | grep jile` and lets see the result

Comment: sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
Password:  
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure       # this also not working in my ubuntu

Comment: @jilesinghsorout run these commands: `sudo /bin/bash` then `chsh root -s /bin/bash` aftre all `exit`.  now `sudo su` should work for you I guess. and what you are doing is not chaning directory to `/root` for that you can simply run `cd /root`;

Comment: @Ravexina thank you very much sudo /bin/bash worked for me. i didn't need to run further commands

Comment: @jilesinghsorout you are welcome, I sent my commend as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your root user default shell is: `/bin/ksh`, if nothing works for you, simply run:

```
sudo /bin/bash
```

to get a root shell, after that try again to change your root default shell, if `chsh` doesn't works for you use `usermod -s` instead.

I strongly suggest you to change your default shell; And only use this approach temporary to fix the issue.